# Is the boundry of any open set empty?

Tags: general-topology

Assume $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is an open set, by definition of an open set $\forall x \in S, \exists \epsilon>0, V_\epsilon(x) \subseteq S$.

Does this means that $V_\epsilon(x) \cap S \neq \phi$ and $V_\epsilon(x) \cap \mathbb{R}-S = \phi$ i.e $\partial S$ is empty?

If not, what best describes the boundary of open sets?

I'm new to topology, so sorry if this question is trivial.

Comment: Suppose the open set contains a point of its boundary.  Think about what a neighborhood of that point looks like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $(0,1) \subset \mathbb{R} $, it is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, i.e., where the $V_{\epsilon} (x) =(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Look at your definition of boundary and show that $\lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ is the boundary of $(0,1)$. Then $\partial S$ need not be empty.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this means that $V_\epsilon(x) \cap S \neq \phi$ and $V_\epsilon(x) \cap \mathbb{R}-S = \phi$ i.e $\partial S$ is empty?

The first part is correct, but it does not imply that the boundary of $S$ is empty. What it does essentially show is that no element of $S$ itself is in the boundary of $S$. Yet recall that the boundary of $S$ is not necessarily a subset of $S$.

'Usually' the boundary of an open set will not be empty. For example recall that the closure of $S$, is the union of $S$ and its boundary. Thus, the only way the boundary can be empty is that $S$ is equal to its closure. That is $S$ is open *and* closed.